# JSOUP реализация поиска

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Хочу реализовать поиска пример, использовал

```
String str = "заг";
  Elements elements = document.select("tbody>tr>a[title*="+str+"]" );
```

При

```
<a href="http://сайт.com/30.html" title="заголовок">
```

Как реализовать это при

```
  <td style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;" 
align="justify">заголовок <a href="news_add.php?id=857">подробнее...</a>    </td>
```

И еще вопрос, подскажите на днях хочу влезть в api, подскажите методы. Пока знаю вроде с помощью JSON можно

Comment: Переформулируйте, пж-та, вопрос. Почти ничего не понятно.

Comment: Уточните что именно вам надо получить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, в строку через эдиттекст или поисковой модуль в интерфейсе посылается текст в `String str` и он оставляет результаты только те где имеется ключевое слово которое ты написал. Таким образом я искал информацию, но теперь другой сайт и тут проблема

Comment: Вам надо найти ссылки, в которых есть "подробнее"?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет тоже самое (заголовок) только теперь текст за >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25517772/3212712), используя `:contains(textToFind)`:

```
Elements elements = document.select( "td>a:contains("+str+")" );
```